# Get contact first and last name?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to load a group and then get everyone first and last name. In the debugger it looks like the group is loaded successfully but when I get down to extracting out the users first and last name I get an error that says, "*We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again*".

I'm looking at the documentation for the contact class and it seems like I'm doing it right but the error makes me feel like I'm missing something.

My code:

```
var distrogroup;
var groups = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
for (group in groups) {
  var tmp = groups[group].getGroupName();
  if (groups[group].getGroupName() == 'Phone Bill') {
    distrogroup = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(groups[group]);
  }
}
for (contact in distrogroup) {
  var lastname = distrogroup[contact].getFamilyName();
  var firstname = distrogroup[contact].getGivenName();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to return an array of first and last names? So replacing the last for loop with:

```
var lastname = [];
var firstname = [];
for (var i = 0; i < distrogroup.length; i++) {
  lastname.push(distrogroup[i].getFamilyName());
  firstname.push(distrogroup[i].getGiveName());
}
```

Also, probably nothing to do with the error, but I wonder if the first section of the code could be simplified to:

```
var distrogroup = ContactApp.getContactGroup('Phone Bill').getContacts();
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contactsapp#getContactGroup

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to work. I do want to assign them to an array. The documentation says that .getFamilyName() returns a string so it seems like what you wrote should work. I know that distrogroup is populated with the right number of Contact objects.

Comment: Another update. I added a line that said `email.push(distrogroup[i].getEmails());` and that did successfully return the email fields for a user. I also exported the users contact info so I know there is information in the family and given name fields.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as the correct answer. I don't know what the issue was but the script is working fine this morning even though I haven't changed it from last night. Thanks for the help.